# Basic geometry in Clojure

Tags: math, clojure, geometry

I'm looking for a Clojure library to do some basic geometry, such as:

- Calculating the slope of a line given its starting and ending coordinates
- Given a line with a known slope, and an x value, calculating the y value (and calculating x given y)

I can write these quite easily, given the mathematical definitions of the equations, but it seems a shame to do so if there is a decent library out there that does this already.

Note that I don't need to plot things graphically and so on, so a library that introduces a lot of graphical dependencies is not really welcome.

Comment: If you can't find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/clojure?) or [Clojars](https://clojars.org/search?q=geometry), then it probably doesn't exist. Why not create one?

Comment: Looks like I might have to roll it myself, as I've not found anything yet.

Comment: There is some code at https://github.com/danielgrigg/sligeom , though I don't have time to see if that's what you'd need. If it is please answer your own question with it. HTH

Comment: sligeom seems to be aimed at 3D graphics. There's a bunch of matrix stuff in there. Not really what I need for this project, but it looks pretty useful in general. Thanks!

Comment: much of the matrix stuff is there because matrixes are a handy way to express geometric transforms (rotation, scale, shear, flipping, etc. etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think in a case like this, seeing as the functions are so small, it is simpler just to write the functions than to introduce a dependency.

```
(defprotocol Line
  (gradient [this] "The gradient of a line")
  (intercept [this] "The intercept of a line on the y axis")
  (f [this] "The line's function f(x) - takes x, returns y")
  (f-inv [this] "The inverse function f-inv(x) - takes y, return x"))

(defn line
  "Make a Line from a gradient and an intercept"   
  [gradient intercept]
  (reify Line
     (gradient [_] gradient)
     (intercept [_] intercept)
     (f [_] (fn [x] (+ (* gradient x) intercept)))
     (f-inv [_] (fn [y] (/ (- y intercept) gradient)))))

(defn points->line 
  "Make a Line given two (different) points on the line"
  [[x1 y1] [x2 y2]]
  (let [gradient (/ (- y2 y1)
                    (- x2 x1))
        intercept (- y1 (* gradient x1))]
  (line gradient intercept)))
```

Example:

```
(def l (points->line [1 1] [4 2]))
(gradient l) ;=> 1/3
(intercept l) ;=> 2/3
((f l) 4) ;=> 2
((f-inv l) 2) ;=> 4
```

Comment: Really nice stuff, thanks!